# Populating NSTableView from array in Swift (without XCode)

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, nsdictionary, nstableview

I'm trying to develop for OS X without the use of XCode in Swift. I'm running into extreme headaches trying to populate NSTableView from any kind of data source. Here is my code:

```
import Cocoa

class StupidDataSource: NSObject, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    var lib:[NSDictionary] = [["a": "1", "b": "2"],
                              ["a": "3", "b": "4"]]

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return lib.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView,
                   objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?,
                   row: Int) -> AnyObject? {
        let result = lib[row].objectForKey(tableColumn!.identifier)
        return result
    }
}


func make_table(window: NSWindow,
                _ size:(x:Int, y:Int, width:Int, ht:Int),
                _ title:String,
                _ data:StupidDataSource
    )-> NSTableView {
    let tableContainer = NSScrollView(frame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400))
    let tableView = NSTableView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400))
    tableView.setDataSource(data)
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableContainer.documentView = tableView
    tableContainer.hasVerticalScroller = true
    window.contentView!.addSubview(tableContainer)
    return tableView
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    let window = NSWindow()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)
    {
        set_window_args(window, 400, 400, "Ass")
        let dumb_dict = StupidDataSource()
        let tableytable = make_table(window, (100, 100, 0 ,0), "poop", dumb_dict)

        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        window.level = 1
    }
}

let app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
app.setActivationPolicy(.Regular)

let controller = AppDelegate()

app.delegate = controller
app.run()
```

This can be run at the command line with "swift file.swift". I have implemented the methods required for NSTableViewDataSource, and initialized everything correctly according to Apple's documentation, yet nothing shows up in the table. What is missing?

Comment: Where are you setting the table column identifiers? If they are not set, your datasource will return nil.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but it looks to me as though your tableView function is just returning the contents of the relevant row from the dictionary.

I personally return a cell as an NSView? like:-

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
{
    if let cell = myViewBasedTableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView
    {
        cell.textField!.stringValue = "Hello";
        // Instead of "Hello". Put the contents of one element from your
        // dict in here. This func is called automatically for every cell
        // in the grid.

        return cell;
    }
    return myEmptyDefaultCell;
}
```

Having said that maybe your example is correct for Cell Based tableView. I never used one of them so don't know. I always use viewBased table view. I often put little images/icons in the cells as well as text using code like:

```
cell.textField!.stringValue = "Hello";
cell.imageView!.image = smileyFace;
return cell;
```